# Segmentation fault on downgraded pg_restore (Postgresql 10 -> Postgresql 9.5)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pg-dump, pg-restore

On a server with Postgresql 10 did a dump and put it to rsync.net

```
pg_dump -Z1 -Fc <db_name> | ssh <user>@s<server> "dd of=dump"
```

On the other server with Postgresql 9.5 downgraded created dump and tried to restore database. Steps were

```
cat dump | sed '/AS integer/d' > downgraded_dump.sql

pg_restore -j 2 -d <db> downgraded_dump.sql
```

On pg_restore failed with *Segmentation fault*.

I have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: You're moving from one unsupported EOL version, to an even older unsupported EOL version. What is the exact patch number of your 9.5 installation? The last one was version 9.5.25, released back in February 2021. In September 2021 a bug was found that also caused a segmentation fault, could be related, and is not fixed for version 9.5 because that version was already EOL.

Comment: Using sed to edit a binary file is surely a suspicious thing to be doing.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: @Frank Heikens yes, I slip on a 9.5.25 version. Is there how can downgrade version? In this case there is an old server where 9.5 Postgresql need to be installed.

Comment: @jjanes thank you for a note. Let me know how it would work the best?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to downgrade PostgreSQL, your only hope is a "plain format" dump (`pg_dump -F p`). Other dump formats keep track of the archive version, and will refuse to restore the dump if the version changed between the releases.

You can try to restore the plain format dump into the older PostgreSQL version, but the first attempt will probably fail. Then you have to edit the SQL script and modify the syntax so that it can be restored into the older PostgreSQL version.

It is a tedious procedure, but then downgrade is not supported in PostgreSQL.

Comment: pg_restore from v9.5 actually won't immediately complain about restoring an unmutilated custom format dump generated by pg_dump from v10.  It is not likely to succeed, but will fail with less obvious reasons than a version complaint.  (But not a segfault, as far as I can see)

Comment: @jjanes If I try to restore with pg_restore v9.5 a custom format dump taken with pg_dump v15, I get the message "pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.15) in file header".

Comment: Right, but he is (presumably) using pg_dump from v10, and the header didn't change from 9.5 to 10

Comment: @jjanes Ah, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to convert the binary dump file to a plain text file, then apply `sed` to that, and send that output to psql.

```
pg_restore dump | sed '/AS integer/d' | psql -d db_name
```

This should succeed as long as the v10 database uses no features which are not backwards compatible with v9.5 other than the change in sequences you are already trying to account for.  There is also a chance some of your text data fields will contain the string 'AS integer' and so get mangled by the sed.  It is not feasible to use the -j option in this case.

This assumes you are using pg_restore from 9.5.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes. Looks like it doesn't work. It came with an error:
sed: couldn't write 77 items to stdout: Broken pipe; pg_restore: [archiver] could not write to output file: Broken pipe

Comment: @fueggit Those sound like simple follow-on errors to something which went wrong with psql.  They couldn't write their entire output, because psql wouldn't read it.  The key to this would be why psql failed.  Look back in your terminal to see what error was reported for that, or break the pipeline up in intermediate files so you don't have so much going on at once.